# CSS 3D transforms: inverted element selection

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, transform

My issue might be a little complicated to I'm using screenshots to illustrate my problem properly. If I talk about a Browser, I always refer to the latest version.

I built a room with 3D transforms.

This is the room in Chrome

[image]

If I hover the elements in the dev tools inspector, every element is highlighted properly (blue) except the floor.

This is how the floor is highlighted:

[image]

It basically highlights the vanishing point (or how the floor would look if it'd be infinitely big).

Now I wouldn't have a problem with the dev tools highlighting. The problem is that firefox won't show the floor like that. Here is firefox - highlighting the same part - not showing the floor:

[image]

The floor is rotated with `transform: rotateX(90deg)`. Here's whats confusing me the most. If I move the floor back for -35px, there is no highlight at all. *For exactly -36px, the floor is correctly highlighted and visible!*

This is Chrome showing the floor with the addition of `translate3d(0px, -35px, 0px)`. The highlight is missing! (I removed the wall to better see the floor)

[image]

And this is chrome with `translate3d(0px, -36px, 0px)`.

[image]

The floor is highlighted correctly! Same in firefox, which is now correctly displaying the floor!

[image]

The disapearing of the floor (in FF) and wrong selection via dev tools (chrome & ff) is only appearing in rotation of the floor around it's x-axis between 80 and 100 degrees. Below and above the floor is highlighted and marked correctly. Same for chrome except that chrome is displaying the floor even though it's weirdly (wrongly?) highlighted in dev tools.

This is firefox showing the floor with 60 degree rotation instead of 90 (and no `translate3d` applied.

[image]

So my conclusion is that if I fix the highlighting in dev tools, I will be able to see the floor in Firefox.
And as both, Firefox and Chrome are highlighting the floor like that, I'd assume this is desired behaviour. Can anyone explain this to me?

This is the CSS (.scss) powering the room:

```
$baseX: 718px;
$baseY: 432px;
$catwalkWidth: 182px;
$wallDistance: 1535px;

section {

    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;

    background-image: url(../img/bg.jpg);
    background-position: left top;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;

    perspective: 1500px;
    perspective-origin: 638px 305px;

    overflow: hidden;

    transition: all ease 1s;
}

.wall {

    width: $baseX;
    height: $baseY;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    background-color: orange;

    transform: translateZ(-0px);

    z-index: 100;
    box-shadow: inset 0 -10px 10px -10px #666;

    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,#e8dad1 67%,#e8dad1 67%,#dedddc 100%);

}


.back-wall {
    width: $catwalkWidth;
    height: $baseY;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: $baseX;
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,#e8dad1 67%,#e8dad1 67%,#dedddc 100%);
    opacity: .9;
    z-index: 50;
    transform: translateZ(-495px);

}

.side-wall-1 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    height: $baseY;
    right: $baseX + $catwalkWidth;
    width: 750px;
    opacity: .5;
    z-index: 105;
    transform-origin: right bottom;
    transform: rotateY(90deg) translateX(-100px);
}

.side-wall-2 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    height: $baseY;
    right: $baseX + $catwalkWidth;
    width: 200px;
    opacity: .5;
    z-index: 105;
    transform-origin: right bottom;
    transform: rotateY(90deg) translateX(-650px);
}

.floor {
    position: absolute;
    width: $baseX;
    height: $wallDistance;
    top: $baseY;
    background-color: blue;
    right: 0;
    transform-origin: top center;
    transform: rotateX(90deg);

    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,#e8dad1 67%,#e8dad1 67%,#dedddc 100%);

    box-shadow: inset 10px 0px 10px -10px #666;

}

.inner {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,#e8dad1 67%,#e8dad1 67%,#dedddc 100%);

}

.catwalk {


    z-index: 10;

    width: 182px;
    height: 1835px;
    position: absolute;
    right: $baseX;
    top: $baseY;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transform: rotateX(90deg) rotateZ(0deg) translateY(-495px) translateZ(3px);
    transform-origin: top center;

    overflow: visible;


    .inner {

        transform-style: preserve-3d;

        &:after {

            @extend .inner;

            content: "";
            display: block;

            right: auto;
            left: 100%;

            transform-origin: left top;

            transform: rotateY(90deg) !important;

            width: 3px;
            background: #666;


        }


    }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like this is happening when an element is "too long/high". I'm not sure exactly what too long is but reducing the height (which was the deepness on the z-axis in my example) fixed the problem.
To keep the room effect and "deepness" I adapted the `perspective` property to create the same room dimensions with smaller elements.